# School project error when clicking login (username and password)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a small school project; the initial part will ask for username and password. When I test by entering the username and password, then clock login, it closes immediately without warning. I am not seeing the error.

Here is my mainactivity.java.

```
package com.example.stengel.dbtest;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void btnLogin_onClick(View oView){

        TextView txtUsername;
        String sUsername;
        TextView txtPassword;
        String sPassword;
        boolean bUserFound = false;
        DBManager oDBManager = new DBManager(this);

        txtUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edTxtUserName);
        sUsername = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        txtPassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edTxtPassword);
        sPassword = txtPassword.getText().toString();


        oDBManager.open();
        Cursor oDBCursor = oDBManager.getAllContacts();

        if(oDBCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                if(oDBCursor.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase(sUsername)){

                    bUserFound = true;

                    if(oDBCursor.getString(2).equalsIgnoreCase(sPassword)){
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Successful login!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Password is wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }while(oDBCursor.moveToNext());

            if(!bUserFound){
                Toast.makeText(this,"User not found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"No users in DB!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        oDBManager.close();
    }

// If creating a new account enable (make visible) icons and colors
public void btnCreateAccount_onClick(View oView) {

    View bView = findViewById(R.id.hScrollView);
    View bView2 = findViewById(R.id.hScrollView2);
    // -- set both to visible - possibly do same for Create Button and disable Create Account button
    bView.setVisibility(bView.VISIBLE);
    bView2.setVisibility(bView.VISIBLE);
}

// create account and add username, password, icon, and color.
// will need to add icon and color options to database
public void btnCreateNewAccount_onClick(View oView){
    DBManager oDBManager = new DBManager(this);

    oDBManager.open();
    TextView txtUsername = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edTxtUserName);
    TextView txtPassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edTxtUserName);
    //increase size of database and add icon and colors
    oDBManager.insertContact(txtUsername.getText().toString(), txtPassword.getText().toString());
    //// make sure text fields are cleared now (username and password fields)
    oDBManager.close();
}//create account method
}
```

This is the DBManager.java

---

```
package com.example.stengel.dbtest;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

//constant variables below
public class DBManager {
    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String TAG = "DBManager";
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table IF NOT EXISTS users (_id integer primary key  autoincrement, "
                    + "username text not null, password text not null);";
    final Context context;
    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBManager(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
    //---opens the database---
    public DBManager open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
    //---insert a contact into the database---
    public long insertContact(String username, String password)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    //---deletes a particular contact---
    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
    //---retrieves all the contacts---
    public Cursor getAllContacts()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME,
                KEY_PASSWORD}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    //---retrieves a particular contact---
    public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                                KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    //---updates a contact---
    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String username, String password)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        args.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

It looks like it blows up in MainActivity on the line 'oDBManager.open();'

Any thoughts?

Comment: you can check in Android Monitor the stracktrace. put it here.

Comment: It is saying the column password is not in the table:  E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts has no column named password
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting password=Password username=Ron
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(password,username) VALUES (?,?)
                      at

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you are creating table `users`

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS users (_id integer primary key  autoincrement, "
                + "username text not null, password text not null);
```

Now during insert operation you are adding

```
db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
```

values to `contacts` table which has no column `password` or `username`

so change the table name properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the table errors and confusion.  With that fixed I am still having a problem with the app stopping at 'oDBManager.open();'

I decided to clean, rebuild and use a new API build, instead of 25 I am using 21 and it is working fine. I go back to 25 and it fails. So will not worry about the reason at this point just knowing cleaning and rebuilding with an earlier version is a valid test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change

```
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "users";
```

You have create table name with Table name "users" not "contacts".